# NUnit run fails the second time I open my just saved .nunit project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, user-interface, nunit

I'm going crazy with this NUnit GUI unexpected behaviour:

**1)** I run nunit-x86.exe, then I select `File \ New Project \ name the .nunit project` and `Save` , **2)** select `Project \ Add Assembly` and select the .dll file related to my test asm , **3)** NUnit gui load all the test classes tree correctly , **4)** I run the X test class and everything goes fine , **5)** I run the Y test class and everything goes fine
... I run others test classes or test methods and everything goes fine , **6)** Then I save the project (`File \ Save`) and close the NUnit program , **7)** I open the just saved .nunit project , **8)** NUnit GUI program loads the test tree correctly but when I go to run a test method or a test class then the run fails. The error is an Exception

> TestAsm.TestClass.TestMethod: System.BadImageFormatException : Could not 
>   load file or assembly 'ASM, Version= xxx, Culture= yyy, PublicKeyToken= zzz' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

What am I forgetting to check or set? Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve my problem I run NUnit-x86.exe, then click on File\Open Project... and select the previously saved .nunit project. (It works also if you select File\Recent Projects).

Answer (score 0):

Check the target framework version of your assembly are same as nUnit test runner supports. See runFile.exe.config for list of supported runtimes.

This exception often seems to be related to X86 vs X64 issues.

Comment: About your hint I previously added the following line `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />` inside the runFile.exe.config because I use some dll related to the framework number 4.0 and 4.5. Is it right?

Comment: Not sure if you just can add entries there.
Are your test assemblies and assemblies under test built for the same framework version and CPU architecture (x86 or x64)?

Comment: I read about the .config file here: http://www.howtosolutions.net/2013/04/solving-nunit-gui-test-load-failed-error-unable-to-find-test-in-assembly-visual-studio/#.VRJub-GhtZp. About your last question: yes, they are.